# Mongo aggregation with two fields match

Tags: mongodb

I had a working aggregation where the match was done between a field and a computed value. But then I realized I need to search by both computed values so I introduced two new fields. I need to aggregate with the match by both of them but I failed to construct mongo query. Either it matches nothing or everything. I am stuck as I have tried so many possibilities. Can you find what do I do wrong?

Data model:

```
db.items.find({"info.slug": "otaceni-na-dalnici"});
{ "_id" : "1e44kgsl1s", "info" : { "slug" : "otaceni-na-dalnici"}, "votes_count" : 9 }

db.poll_votes.find({poll: "1e44kgsl1s", user: "1e41795qjw"});
{ "_id" : "1e44kgsl1s_1e41795qjw", "poll" : "1e44kgsl1s", "user": "1e41795qjw", "vote" : "dislike"}
```

Original query:

```
db.items.aggregate([{$match: {"info.slug": "otaceni-na-dalnici"}},
{$lookup: {
    from: 'poll_votes',
    let: {poll_id: "$_id"},
    pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", {$concat: ["$$poll_id", "_1e41795qjw"]}]}}}, 
    {$project: {_id: 0, vote: "$vote"}}],
    as: "me"
}}]).pretty();
```

And its simplified response:

```
{
    "_id" : "1e44kgsl1s",
    "info" : {
            "slug" : "otaceni-na-dalnici",
    },
    "votes_count" : 9,
    "me" : [{"vote" : "dislike"}]
}
```

New query that uses `poll` and `user` fields.

```
db.items.aggregate([{$match: {"info.slug": "otaceni-na-dalnici"}},
{$lookup: {
        from: 'poll_votes', 
        let: {poll_id: "$_id"},
        pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$and: [{poll: "$$poll_id"}, {user: "1e41795qjw"}]}}},
        {$project: {_id: 0, vote: "$vote"}}], as: "me"
    }
}]);
```

but though there is `$and` operator, it returns `poll_votes` for all users.

```
 {
 "_id": "1e44kgsl1s",
 "info": {"slug": "otaceni-na-dalnici"},
 "votes_count": 9,
 "me": [{"vote": "dislike"}, {"vote": "neutral"}, {"vote": "neutral"}, {"vote": "neutral"}, {"vote": "hate"}, {"vote": "neutral"}, {"vote": "trivial"}]
```

}

What is wrong? I have tried to set up the mongo sandbox but it does not recognize my aggregate query. Here are test data

```
db={
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "1e44kgsl1s",
            "info": {
                "slug": "otaceni-na-dalnici"
            },
            "votes_count": 9
        }
    ],
    "poll_votes": [
        {
            "_id": "1e44kgsl1s_1e41795qjw",
            "poll": "1e44kgsl1s",
            "user": "1e41795qjw",
            "vote": "dislike"
        },
        {
            "_id": "xyz",
            "poll": "1e44kgsl1s",
            "user": "abc",
            "vote": "dislike"
        },
        {
            "_id": "ijk",
            "poll": "1e44kgsl1s",
            "user": "qwerty",
            "vote": "dislike"
        },

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing both the normal mongo query language and aggregation operators inside the `$expr`.

The predicates that require the variable should be inside `$expr`, and the normal ones shouldn't:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match: {"info.slug": "otaceni-na-dalnici"}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'poll_votes', 
        let: {poll_id: "$_id"},
        pipeline: [
        {$match: {$and: [
                    {$expr: {$eq:["$poll", "$$poll_id"]}}, 
                    {user: "1e41795qjw"}
        ]}}
    }},
    {$project: {_id: 0, vote: "$vote"}}], as: "me"}
}]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eOVvj5JQDYc)

Comment: The query in playground works, the query in the answer has a syntax error. Thank you for hint. I will study a differences.

Comment: I misunderstood a documentation: A $match stage requires the use of an $expr operator to access the variables